# Compare Array value with hash and delete key if it matches in a file

Tags: perl

I have `.txt` file with 3 columns. I want to compare the first with the second column and if values from the first column appear in the second column, I want to delete that entry in the second and third column (first column should not be modified). The result should be stored in a new file.

Example input:

```
Col 1                  Col 2              Col 3
VIBHAR_02293_1   VIBHAR_00819_2     tatatattattata
VIBHAR_00819_2   VIBHAR_00819_4     tattavgaggagag
VIBHAR_00705_3   VIBHAR_00705_7     attaggaccaggat
VIBHAR_00819_4   VIBHAR_02153_9     ccagggattattat
```

Example output:

```
VIBHAR_02293_1   VIBHAR_00705_7     attaggaccaggat
VIBHAR_00819_2   VIBHAR_02153_9     ccagggattattat
VIBHAR_00705_3   
VIBHAR_00819_4
```

I tried using following code but it did not work:

```
while($line=(<File>))
{
chomp($line);
@F=split('\t',$line);
    $hash{$F[1]}=$F[2];
    if ($F[0] eq $F[1])
    {
#        print "$line\n";
         delete($hash{keys});
    }
}
```

If the format of the columns which I posted above is not good then, only my question is enough I guess.

Comment: Your shift key seems to have a life of its own.

Comment: I tried to make heads or tails of your example, until I realized that column 1 is completely independent. There does not seem to be a sane reason to keep it all in one file. If you split them into two files, it's easy. If you insist on keeping one file, a two-pass aporoach would seem natural; on the first pass, read the first column, and on the second pass, read the other two, discarding any entry where the key field was also seen in the first pass.

Comment: You may want to look at the CPAN bio namespace (https://metacpan.org/search?q=Bio) to see if there's an existing module you can use.

Comment: @ Triplee, even if i split the 1st Col with rest two in other How do i do that opening 2 file and then split the 2nd file with \t, same as my code above or some other way,, in my code above Delete isn't working,, so could you plz give some snippets,,,:-)

Comment: @Oesor: Thank u very much, I dint know there is Bio modules in CPAN,, thank u,, will go through em,,

Comment: @Kiran: http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %H;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @F = split /\t/;
    $H{$F[0]} = [$., $F[1], $F[2]];
}

my @col1;
my @col23;

for my $col1 (sort { $H{$a}[0] <=> $H{$b}[0] } keys %H) {
    push @col1, $col1;
    next if exists $H{ $H{$col1}[1] };
    push @col23, [@{ $H{$col1} }[1,2]];
}

for my $i (0 .. $#col1) {
    print $col1[$i];
    print "\t", join "\t", @{ $col23[$i] } if $i < @col23;
    print "\n";
}
```

Do you really want to "move up" the values in columns 2 and 3?

Comment: Nope, moving up the value aren't Necessary,, i m trying with ur code its juz displaying the whole file itself

Comment: @Kiran: Strange, for me it returns your expected output.

Comment: i seem to be doing wrong kindly check dis code n correct if any,same i copy pasted juz edited opening file n split..plz don mind still im beginner specially HASHES.open (File,'file.txt');
my %H;
while (<File>) {
    chomp;
    @F=split('\t',$_);
    $H{$F[0]} = [$_, $F[1], $F[2]];
}

Comment: @Kiran: Nope, it's not right. In split, the first argument should be a regular expression, not a string. Also, the first member of the array is `$.`, not `$_`.